# Looking for a quick method to evaluate an expression of polynomial roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

So define a polynomial $P(x) = 4x^3 + 4x - 5 = 0$, whose roots are $a, b $ and $c$. Evaluate the value of $(b+c-3a)(a+b-3c)(c+a-3b)$

Now  tried this in two ways (both failed because it was far too messy)

1. Expand everything out (knew this was definitely not the required answer but I cant think of the quick method myself)
2. Using sum and product (which is still quite lengthy but better)

Of course the above methods relied on the use of Vieta's sum/product of roots.

Does anyone have an amazing concise solution for me? I know you guys are full of tricks, and I enjoy reading them.

Comment: For a start : Vieta gives us $a+b+c=0$ , not sure how useful this is here.

Comment: Is that $-3a$ in the first bracket rather than $-31$? Note that the sum of the roots of the original equation is zero.

Comment: Yes it is @MarkBennet thanks; and fixed. Ok I see about noticing that. I wish I could've noticed that in my exam though! Under stress those things tend to slip by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

- $b+c-3a=a+b+c-4a=-4a$;
- $a+b-3c=a+b+c-4c=-4c$;
- $c+a-3b=a+b+c-4b=-4b$.

So, you're after $(-4a)\times(-4c)\times(-4b)=-64abc$. But you know that $abc=\frac54$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $b+c-3a = (a+b+c)-4a = -4a$ and everything simplifies easily.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a+b+c=0, ab+bc+ca=1, abc=5/4$
Le $y=a+b-3c=a+b+c-4c=-4c \implies y=-4x$
Let us transform $x^3+4x-5=0$ bt $x=y/-4$ to get a the $y$ equation
$4(y/-4)^3+4(-y/4)-5=0 \implies y^3+16y+80=0$
The y$y$ equation will have the required roots.
So the product of roots is $y_1y_2y_3=-80.$